# Use Bootstrap's utility API from my scss file

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-5, scss-mixins

The Bootstrap docs explain how to [enable](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/spacing/#negative-margin) negative margins - but that is for the case where one customises Bootstrap.

I'm using it from a CDN, but I still want those classes (e.g. `mt-n1`). I'd like to import them via a mixin (or something like that) into my scss. The ["Utility API"](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/spacing/#utilities-api) shows that is possible, but I'm unsure how to invoke it from my scss file.

How do I do that?

For example:

```scss
// import bootstrap
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities";

// generate negative margin from $utilities:"negative-margin"
// ... <---what goes here?
```

I tried `@include generate-utility("negative-margin")` but that fails.

Comment: You can't update CDN pack, because it's CSS. But you can include (generate) only this part of BS with custom utilities in case you will add BS package into your project. If it possible for you - I can add some example

Comment: @YaroslavTrach Yes - I want to use the CDN css, and in my custom scss I want to import / use / mixin / reference / (?) the bootstrap stuff in that "utility api"... But I dont know how :-)

Comment: OK, you can do that in case you can download or install BS package to you vendor/node_modules folder. Could you?

Comment: @YaroslavTrach Yes I have bootstrap in my `node_modules/bootstrap`, and I already use it for "mixins". But I don't know how to use the "utility api". Please see my edit to the question for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set BS5 variable `$enable-negative-margins` to `true` and insert it before `variables.scss` include.

Then, remove all utilities, and include only ones you want, see example:

```scss
// enabling negative margins
$enable-negative-margins: true;

@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities";

// remove all utilities and include only what you want
$utilities: (
  (
    "negative-margin": map-get($utilities, "negative-margin"),
    "negative-margin-x": map-get($utilities, "negative-margin-x"),
    "negative-margin-y": map-get($utilities, "negative-margin-y"),
    "negative-margin-top": map-get($utilities, "negative-margin-top"),
    "negative-margin-end": map-get($utilities, "negative-margin-end"),
    "negative-margin-bottom": map-get($utilities, "negative-margin-bottom"),
    "negative-margin-start": map-get($utilities, "negative-margin-start"),
  )
);

// generate utilities
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities/api";
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Wow that's incredible, it even generates the classes for each breakpoint - thanks Yaroslav!

Comment: You are welcome) Now it's flexible)

Answer (score -1):

@YaroslavTrach's answer is CORRECT.

But until he explained how to do it properly, I was using a workaround. I'm adding it here for those who don't use scss, or don't have a *node-based build environment* in their project.

I added the regular `mt-1` etc. classes to my custom css, and modified their names and values:

```css
.mt-n1 { margin-top: -0.25rem !important; }
.mt-n2 { margin-top: -0.5rem !important; }
.mt-n3 { margin-top: -1rem !important; }
.mt-n4 { margin-top: -1.5rem !important; }
.mt-n5 { margin-top: -3rem !important; }
```

But if you do have a node-based build environment for your frontend, I recommend the accepted answer as it adds classes for every breakpoint.